# I have a nextjs app that runs fin on Dev on my laptop. Discover that after deployment, data fetching is not working. User and admin update not working

Tags: vercel, next.js13

My Nextjs application was working fine on DEV on my laptop. But after deployment on Vercel i discover the user update is not reflecting. So, i want to know how to handle data revalidation and caching.

I updated my env files. But the problem is not solved

Comment: What is `the user update is not reflecting`. Please explain with details so we can help you.

Comment: When a user want to change his profile picture or admin want to update a user rol to admin or manager, it is not working on deployment, but working fin on dev, locally on my computer

Comment: How you get data locally? Share the code so we can help you

Comment: Login/Logout, and Register are working fine in both deployment and dev. I have worked on user profile picture, and it is working now, but other other, such as admin adding a new product, or changing a particular user role, they only work after i have pushed my code again to github. But supposed to work  instantly

Comment: What you can do if your site is not in production. `console.log` all points where you this is the bug. Then, push the code or use vercel cli: https://vercel.com/docs/cli

Comment: I have console.log everywhere in my code, but no error is returned. The success update alert will show on the page, but the changes expected will only show when i redeployed my app again.

Comment: In vercel, go to your project and re-deploy the project